# Ленивая регулярка с конца строка

Tags: регулярные-выражения

```
' 8 minutes ago, 5.79.70.34[a.teletom.ru]...91.77.160.189[hon]
```

Хочу вытащить данные между скобками [].

```
(?=\[).+?(?=\])
```

Данная регулярка берёт совпадения с начала строки, а хочется с конца. Как сделать?

Comment: я не уврене что lib в вашем языке позволит обрабатываться rex до первого совпадения и прироста не будет и проше будет брать пследний элемент. 

а для увелечения скорости обрабатывать списки строк в обратном прядке

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2482145/7791165